# How to add to a variable using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add +1 to the variable 'score' when the button with ID = #correct is clicked on.

I am new to coding, can anyone figure out why the var score remains 0, please?

**javascript/jQuery code**

```
var score = 0

$('table tr td button').on('click', function(){
  if ($(this).is("#correct"))
    $(this).addClass("theright") && score++ && $('.q1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  else {
    $(this).addClass("thewrong") && $('.q1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

Comment: don't shortcut like that - for one thing, if first time `if ($(this).is("#correct"))` is `true` the code after `score++` won't execute, since `0` is falsey .... guess you could do `++score` instead ... really though, you're repeating `$('.q1').attr('disabled', 'disabled')` in both cases, so move that after the the if/else ... and just don't shortcut like that

Comment: my guess is `$(this).is("#correct")` is not true - try `console.log($(this).is("#correct"))` to see

Answer (score 0):

How did you use your variable score maybe the problem lies there cause I did try your code and its working fine

```js
var score = 0

$('button').on('click', function(){
  if ($(this).is("#correct"))
    $(this).addClass("theright") && score++ && $('.q1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  else {
    $(this).addClass("thewrong") && $('.q1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
  
  $("span#score").html(score)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="score"></span><br><br>
<button id="correct">Correct</button>
<button>Wrong</button>
```